# Copy file from Slave Hudson to Master Hudson

Tags: hudson

I'm Having Hudson1 (Linux), creating a Build and doing other jobs for a certain project,
And Having Hudson2 (Windows), creating a build and doing other jobs for another different project,
Hudson2 build depends on Hudson1 build,

P1 : I set Hudson2 as a slave on Hudson1 and with "Copy to Slave plugin" I can copy result build of Hudson1 to Hudson2,

Now the question is, can I copy result build of Hudson1 to Hudson2, considering Hudson2 as Master and Hudson2 as slave, without an ant script that uses FTP or SCP command,

Note we only use JNLP protocol to connect master to slave,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See pugin documentation https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin, both copy directions are supported.

However, I am not sure what you mean by hudson1 and hudson2. Do you mean one master and a slave or two master? If the second is the case, then Copy to Slave plugin doesn't help you in either direction.