# Jenkins slave/master setup to pick up result files

Tags: jenkins

I have the jenkins `master` running on `Machine X`. I have `slave` running on `Machine Y`. Now I have a job that runs on `master` and outputs a file in the `master` machine. I have another job (Database loader job) that runs on the `master` that pickup the aforementioned file and writes it to a database.

Now if I run another job in `slave` `Machine Y` it also outputs a file in `Machine Y` in a certain directory. But now if I run the Database loader job it will obviously look for the output file in the `master` machine which is `Machine X`.

I don't want to create a new job that will run on the `slave` machine just for the directory change sake.

How do I handle this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy file from Slave Hudson to Master Hudson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600792/copy-file-from-slave-hudson-to-master-hudson)

Answer (score 0):

Consider those two options:

- [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) which adds a build step to copy artifacts from another project.
- Or use [Node Label Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) to trigger downstream job targeting specific machine.